# Can anybody tell me what am i doing wrong with the following program? I am getting errors like <identifier expected> and " '; expected"

Tags: java

The code is :

```
    import java.util.*;

public class hippotest{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
Hippo h=new Hippo("JP");
System.out.println(h.getname());
}
}

abstract class Animal{
private String name;

public Animal(String new){ 
name=new; 
}

public String getname(){
return name;
}

}

class Hippo extends Animal{

public Hippo(String name){
super(name);
}

}
```

I am getting  error and " ';' expected" error. I have got no idea why this is happening, can somebody please help me out?.

Comment: on which line do you get this?

Comment: Make it habit of marking the answer which you think is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`new` will not be a variable name because it is **reserved keyword** in java. So change new to another name.

```
public class hippotest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Hippo h = new Hippo("JP");
        System.out.println(h.getname());
    }
}

abstract class Animal {
    private String name;

    public Animal(String nameAnimal) { // new needs to be changed
        name = nameAnimal; //new is reserved keyword
    }

    public String getname() {
        return name;
    }
}

class Hippo extends Animal {
    public Hippo(String name) {
        super(name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`new` is a reserved keyword, so you cannot use it as a name of variable. Rename it.